# How to send more than 3 parameters in CodeIgniter route as one string

Tags: php, string, codeigniter, parsing, routes

This seems really basic but i can't get the hang of it.

I'm trying to send more then one parameter to a method in the controller, like i mentioned below

```
http://localhost/<project>/coupons/
```

My Route
$route['c(:any)(:any)(:any)(:any)(:any)(:any)'] = "blog/coupons_page/$1/$2";

"C" will remain constant by other words will be change how can i parse to controller
can any one guid

Answer (score 1):

```
$actual_link  = "0$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

Need to separate them?

```
$separator    = explode("/",$actual_link); 
$separated1   = $separator[0];
$separated2   = $separator[1]; //And so on//
```